# Represent JSON in ext.data.model

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a controller function that returns json string like this:

```
 [
    { "id": 5, "label": "label1", "type": 1, "arr": [0,1,1,2,3,1,2,0]},
    { "id": 6, "label": "label2", "type": 2, "arr": [1,1,2,2,3,1,2,3]}
 ]
```

I want to create apropriate ext.data.model for this json so that when my store reads the json it works properly.

How would the model look like? I have no idea

So far I have this model

```
   Ext.define('MyModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'label', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'type', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'arr', type: 'auto'}
        ]
    });
```

And this store

```
   // The data store containing the list of states
    var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'MyModel',

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/url/to/jsonpage',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'MyModel'
            }
        }
        //autoLoad: true,
        //autoSync:true
    });
```

Comment: Looks good. What are your errors? What are your Question? (your root data looks odd, I guess you could leave it blank? Or why do you named it like the model?)

Comment: I want to use the store in a combobox. The problem is that the select event of the combobox component is fired only once, which appears that problem exists. I think that is it due to the model or the store itself. I can see the labels though

Comment: I changed it to MyModel.